# If-statement with list comprehension

Tags: python

I'd like to write a bit more compact the following statement:

```
if day == "monday" and element[0] == 1:
    # code A
elif day == "tuesday" and element[0] == 2:
    # code A (the same)
#and so on...
```

I thought of list comprehensions, where the first list contains all week-days: ["monday", "tuesday"] #and so on 
and the second list integers: [1, 2] # and so on

Is this possible write the if-statement a bit compacter?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know numbers starting with 0 are actually octal numbers in Python 2?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing - I don't think a list comp is relevant here, but perhaps a dictionary `{('monday', 001): some_func}` (you know leading zero means octal, right?)

Comment: A dictionary, even if the code which is executed is always the same? 
And yes, the ints should start with 1, not 001. Sorry.

Comment: Given that the OP is working with the days of the week, he is probably okay with using octal integer literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand exactly what you're after, but one thing that can often help is to factor out long(ish) partial expressions, such as `element[0]` that clutter the code.

Consider something like:

```
here = (day, element[0])

if here == ("monday", 1):
  # Code A
elif here == ("tuesday", 2):
  # Code B
```

It's at least a bit denser, i.e. less repetetive and with more focus on the important parts since it "folds" the `and` into comparing tuples instead. The word `here` is very much a placeholder, it should probably be something that makes actual sense in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a list comprehension, which is what one would use in creating a list.

If you want to process two lists of data in step, then the zip() builtin is what you want:

```
days = "mon tue wed thu fri sat sun".split()
daynums = range(1,7+1)

element = (6, 100)
day = "sat"

for dayname, daynum in zip(days,daynums):
    if day == dayname and element[0] == daynum:
       print "there is a match!"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `# code A` is the same for all days, how about this

```
days = set(enumerate(["monday", "tuesday", ...], 1))

if (element[0], day) in days:
    # code A
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you want to run code A if the index of the day name matches the value of element[0]. If that is so, then this does what you want:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def main():

    weekdays = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
        "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

    #Build a set of (daynumber, dayname) tuples
    day_elements = set(enumerate(weekdays, 1))

    #Print day_elements to check that it's what we want
    for i,v in day_elements:
        print i, v
    print

    #................

    day = "thursday"
    element = [4]

    if (element[0], day) in day_elements:
        print "Calling code A"
    else:
        print "Whoops!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```